# Localhost not loading on mobile device

Tags: html, css, apache, server, xampp

As the title states, my iMac won't allow mobile devices to connect to the web server. I can access localhost via

```
localhost
192.168.1.187:1717
```

These both work on my iMac and also my MacBook however the funny/weird issue is that the mobile device won't load it. I mean the files are hosted on the iMac and are accessible completely (both on localhost and the IP address) and the site also works on my MacBook (On the IP address) however my mobile device won't load it. Why?

I've disabled my firewall, changed ports through XAMPP and messed around with Apache Config but no to avail.

(This is definitely not a duplicate as EVERY question I've read the IP address doesn't work on the local machine but for me it does)

Comment: I doubt your last statement...

Comment: So what happens if you try to load the resource on that mobile device? Do you get an error? Which? Tell us!

Comment: Are you _really_ sure (I mean _really_) that the mobile device is in the same network as those desktop systems? How did you check that?

Comment: @arkascha Well, I have one WiFi network at home and they're all connected to it. No public WiFi's or my neighbours WiFi, none of that. The error I get is the usual error you get when you can't access a website (This site can't be reached)

Comment: Do you see the requests in your http servers access log files?

Comment: @arkascha From the iMac and MacBook, Yes. The mobile device, no.

Comment: Then use a network sniffer (e.g. wireshark) to monitor the local network. Do you see the requests? I bet those requests do _not_ enter your local network but are routed to the mobile network.

Comment: @arkascha Mobile data is off, I'm definitely on the home WiFi.

Comment: So what does the network sniffer show?